# Speak.js – only one command is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, espeak

I'm currently fooling around with speak.js: http://www.syntensity.com/static/espeak.html

Apparently the script only allows for one speak command to be executed, if I do like this:

```
speak("1");
speak("2");
```

... only "2" is read out.

Does anybody know how to troubleshoot a problem like this?

If you want to fiddle around: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/YgWdh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that both are being executed but the first gets trampled by the second. Look at this revision of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YgWdh/4/.

It uses a `setTimeout` to make sure the second line waits a bit before executing. But I don't see any API docs so I don't know how to make the second call wait only long enough for the first to finish.

Comment: Incidentally it's freaky that you can compile from C to Javascript, I never knew that before.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do something like `speak("1 2")`

http://jsfiddle.net/K6GtQ/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any experience with this library, but you might want to delay a time after speaking, because maybe if you let it speak another command right after it, it just overwrites the first speak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194089/speak-js-only-one-command-is-executed/8194167#8194167

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could investigate on meSpeak.js (http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/), which is based on speak.js, and add support for callbacks.
I am in no way affiliated to that project, but I am investigating in something which callbacks help to solve.